# Python argument parser for numerical (float) operations

Tags: command-line-arguments, python-3.5

In my python script, I am doing multiplication on some values in a CSV file. I am trying to use argparse so that I can pass the (float) values (which I want to multiply the CSV values with), something like

`python3 script.py filename.csv 0.5 2 3.5`

I tried doing the argparse as following:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-m", "--multiplier", required = True, help = "number to multiply with x,y,z values")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

and then using `args["multiplier"]` where I am doing the multiplication in the script.

I don't know if I am making a mistake in the code, or while calling the script

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are calling your script.

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-m", "--multiplier", required = True, help = "number to multiply with x,y,z values")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
print(float(args['multiplier']))
```

The code does work as expected. Maybe you are calling it wrong. To call your code :

```
your_prompt$ python3 try.py -m 2
2.0
```

In your code you are specifying an argument -m. So to pass your multiplier to the script you need to add a -m parameter.

Comment: https://github.com/AnanDvd/MPI-Pigino/blob/master/csv_edit_arg.py

Line 42 is where I am trying to use `multiplier`, using the method you suggested.
In the command line, I want to call the file as well. The `multiplier` that we pass in the cmd line, is being used to do the multiplication in the values of the file

Comment: I guess I will have to add another add_argument statement for the file `ap.add_argument("-i", "--file", required=True, help="path to input file")` and replace `f` with `args["file"]` ?